# Flink how to create table with the schema inferred from Avro input data

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have loaded an Avro file in a Flink Dataset:

```java
AvroInputFormat<GenericRecord> test = new AvroInputFormat<GenericRecord>(
        new Path("PathToAvroFile")
        , GenericRecord.class);
DataSet<GenericRecord> DS = env.createInput(test);

usersDS.print();
```

and here are the results of printing the DS:

```java
{"N_NATIONKEY": 14, "N_NAME": "KENYA", "N_REGIONKEY": 0, "N_COMMENT": " pending excuses haggle furiously deposits. pending, express pinto beans wake fluffily past t"}
{"N_NATIONKEY": 15, "N_NAME": "MOROCCO", "N_REGIONKEY": 0, "N_COMMENT": "rns. blithely bold courts among the closely regular packages use furiously bold platelets?"}
{"N_NATIONKEY": 16, "N_NAME": "MOZAMBIQUE", "N_REGIONKEY": 0, "N_COMMENT": "s. ironic, unusual asymptotes wake blithely r"}
{"N_NATIONKEY": 17, "N_NAME": "PERU", "N_REGIONKEY": 1, "N_COMMENT": "platelets. blithely pending dependencies use fluffily across the even pinto beans. carefully silent accoun"}
{"N_NATIONKEY": 18, "N_NAME": "CHINA", "N_REGIONKEY": 2, "N_COMMENT": "c dependencies. furiously express notornis sleep slyly regular accounts. ideas sleep. depos"}
{"N_NATIONKEY": 19, "N_NAME": "ROMANIA", "N_REGIONKEY": 3, "N_COMMENT": "ular asymptotes are about the furious multipliers. express dependencies nag above the ironically ironic account"}
{"N_NATIONKEY": 20, "N_NAME": "SAUDI ARABIA", "N_REGIONKEY": 4, "N_COMMENT": "ts. silent requests haggle. closely express packages sleep across the blithely"}
```

Now I want to create a table from DS Dataset with the exactly the same schema of Avro file, I mean columns should be N_NATIONKEY, N_NAME, N_REGIONKEY, and N_COMMENT.

I know using the line:

```java
tableEnv.registerDataSet("tbTest", DS, "field1, field2, ...");
```

I can create a table and set the columns, but I want the columns to be inferred automatically from data. Is it possible?
In addition, I tried

```java
tableEnv.registerDataSet("tbTest", DS);
```

but it creates a table with the schema:

```java
root
 |-- f0: GenericType<org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GenericRecord` is a black-box for the Table & SQL API runtime as the number of fields and their datatype is undefined. I would recommend to use a Avro-generated class which extends `SpecificRecord`. Those specific types are also recognized by Flink's type system and you can properly address individual fields with proper data type.

Alternatively, you could implement a [custom UDF](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/table/udfs.html#scalar-functions) that extracts fields with a proper datatype `getAvroInt(f0, "myField")`, `getAvroString(f0, "myField")` etc.

Some pseudo code for this:

```
class AvroStringFieldExtract extends ScalarFunction {
    public String eval(GenericRecord r, String fieldName) {
        return r.get(fieldName).toString();
    }
}

tableEnv.registerFunction("getAvroFieldString", new AvroStringFieldExtract())
```

Comment: Thanks, It's a bit confusing for me. Could you give me a simple example of using custom UDF, pls?

Comment: I added a little example to the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Should I extend a ScalarFunction class for every Avro field?

Comment: No, only for the data types that you want to extract. The `fieldName` parameter makes the function universal.